# Get Value Of Control In Code-Behind

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

When I call `<%= this.HiddenField.Value %>` the value of HiddenField control in this case remains the same state (5)  ? But when I call it with `console.log(document.getElementById('<%= this.HiddenField.ClientID %>').value);` this return the changed state in this case "active", why? How I can get the changed value in code behind (I want `<%= this.HiddenField.Value %>` to return "active"(the changed value)) ?

code:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        document.getElementById('<%= this.HiddenField.ClientID %>').value = "active";
        console.log(document.getElementById('<%= this.HiddenField.ClientID %>').value); // this return te changed value "active"
        console.log('<%= this.HiddenField.Value %>') //this again is 5 not "active"
    });
</script>
<asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField" runat="server" Value="5" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are confusing server side and client side code and when they run.

Server side code runs first. This is what's in the `<%=%>` blocks. In it, when using `this.HiddenField.Value`, it will output the *server side* value of the control, before it has been changed client side. `this.HiddenField.ClientID` will output the control ID as output by the server so you can get it from *client side* code.

When the page first loads, the `<%=%>` sections will be replaced with the server side values.

This would look like (in the browser once the page loads do - view source to see what was actually rendered to the browser):

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        document.getElementById('someId').value = "active";
        console.log(document.getElementById('someId').value); // this return te changed value "active"
        console.log('5') //this again is 5 not "active"
    });
</script>
<input type="HiddenField" ID="someId" Value="5" />
```

Then, and only then, will client side code run, with the results you have seen.

Comment: What do you think to do if I want to take in code behind the changed value. I want this.HiddenField.Value to return "active".

Comment: You need to do what you 'va already done. `console.log(document.getElementById('<%= this.HiddenField.ClientID %>').value);`

Comment: @TheChampp - You changed it client side. When you postback, this is the value seen on the server side.

Answer (score 1):

In the following line

```
 console.log('<%= this.HiddenField.Value %>')
```

`<%= this.HiddenField.Value %>` is evaluated at server so in the browser its

```
console.log('5')
```

because that's the value of the expression.

Answer (score 0):

`<%= whatever %>` evaluates `whatever` when the page is rendered on the server.

If you look at the HTML sent to your client, you will find something like

```
$(function () {
    document.getElementById('blahblah_HiddenField').value = "active";
    console.log(document.getElementById('blahblah_HiddenField').value);
    console.log('5')
});
```

The `5` is rendered by the server - there's nothing on the client's end linking that `5` to the value in the hidden field, so it doesn't get updated when the hidden field's value changes.

Answer (score 0):

It happens because the asp.net control shows the "server" value, that is 5. With javascript you are modifing the dom on the client side, the asp.net control value doesn't change until you post the page.

Comment: What to do to take this changed value "active" in server side ?

Comment: You get the value on the server after posting back the page. So on your code behind you can do HiddenField1.Value and you'll have the updated value. But when on the DOM you can only handle elements through javascript, as you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use    **ClientIDMode**

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />
```

**Set and Get;**

*in jquery*

```
$('#HiddenField1').val('active');
console.log($('#HiddenField1').val());
```

*in javascript*

```
document.getElementById('HiddenField1').value = 'active';
console.log(document.getElementById('HiddenField1').value);
```